# Default Rails ActionMailer not delivering multipart emails correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have created, what I thought to be, a MultiPart email using rails but upon delivery to any client it is only ever shown in plain text therefore printing out the headers and all the templating.

```
def order_receipt(order)
  @order = order
  mail subject: "Order #{order.id}"
end

OrderMailer.order_receipt(Order.first).deliver
```

The email I receive in the clients is as such:

```
----==_mimepart_5525126014929_7e3f9b4c1fb98c525c2 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: etc...
```

And then just boxes and text where styled content should be.

Do I need to explicitly set the formats in the mailer like so:

```
def order_receipt(order)
  @order = order
  mail subject: "Order #{order.id}" do |format|
    format.text
    format.html
  end
end
```

because I thought that was the default ActionMailer behaviour

Comment: The default behaviour is to see if there is a plaintext template and an html template.  If there are both then it makes a multipart email, with each part set from the corresponding template.  If there is just one, it doesn't make it multipart.

Comment: This is exactly what I though. We do have both a plain text and html version so I assume it is sending a multipart email. However the client does not seem to read it as HTML and instead has a content type of text/plain. BTW I am using Apple Mail as the client with html emails enabled.

Comment: The best way to look at the email is to log it out, and view it in the log.  It should have `Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=mimepart_<random_string_of_chars>` near the top, and then several sections, seperated by  `--mimepart_<the_same_random_string_of_chars>`

Comment: Thanks @MaxWillians. This is what I ended up doing. The Content-Type was set to text/pain for some reason so I had to explicitly set it to multipart/alternative before delivering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely I had to specify that the content type would be multipart:

```
mail content_type: 'multipart/alternative', subject: "Order #{order.id}"
```

This fixed the issue immediately. I find it very strange that Rails has to be told this. Bug perhaps in the version I am using?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Action Mailer automatically send multipart emails if you have different templates for the same action.

But if this is not the case then you can also pass content-type along with parameter to mail.
for eg.

```
def order_receipt(order)
  @order = order
  mail(content_type: "text/html", subject: "Order #{order.id}")
end
```